# How to check if stdin == stdout in C

Tags: c, stdout, stdin, getchar, putchar

I am building a program that takes user input, manipulates it, and outputs the changes (if any). The guidelines are:

1. Delete all digits
2. if > 2 newlines in a row, print only 2
3. change cases of letters
4. print 2 spaces for each space
5. print all other characters normally
6. Return a 1 from main if the stdin and stdout are the same, a 0 if not.

I cannot use any data structure for this project, so I am using getchar() to read stdin char by char.

Is there any way to compare stdin to stdout in C? I am new to the language and do not know how to even look into this. My code with all guidelines satisfied sans 6 is below:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int newline(int iochar);
void testChars(int iochar);
void upperCase(int iochar);
void lowerCase(int iochar);
void space(int iochar); 
void digit();


int main()
{
    int iochar = 0;
    iochar = getchar();

    testChars(iochar);

    return 0;
}

void testChars(int iochar)
{
    while(iochar != EOF) {
        if (iochar == 10)
            iochar = newline(iochar);

        else if(iochar == 32)
        space(iochar);

        else if (iochar > 64 && iochar < 91)
        upperCase(iochar);

        else if (iochar < 123 && iochar > 96)
        lowerCase(iochar);

        else if (iochar < 58 && iochar > 47)
        digit();

        else putchar(iochar);

        iochar = getchar();
    }
}

void space(int iochar)
{
    putchar(iochar);
    putchar(iochar);
}

int newline(int iochar)
{
    int count = 0;
    while (iochar == 10){
        if(count < 2)
            putchar(iochar);
        count++; 
        iochar = getchar();
    }
    return iochar;
}

void digit()
{
    return;
}

void upperCase(int iochar)
{
    iochar += 32;
    putchar(iochar);
}

void lowerCase(int iochar)
{
    iochar -=32;
    putchar(iochar);
}
```

Comment: You can use the characters like this `'a'` - we don't memorize ascii value - so readability of your code is zero.

Comment: What do you mean with *compare `stdin` with `stdout`*?

Comment: To make an upper case character lower case, consider `iochar += 'a' - 'A';`  A bit easier to understand.  It works in ASCII  and [EBCDIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC) (for those retro minded coders).  The standard way is `iochar = tolower(iochar);`

Comment: (6) in its simplest form `if (stdin == stdout) return 1;` should do. (you can compare pointers of the same type, both are `FILE*`) No tricks.

Comment: Wrong title: `stdin` is always different of `stdout`

Comment: Unless some wicked prof is running the tests of a vm with `/dev/stdin` symlinked to `/dev/stdout` or in an environment that redirects one to the other on a temporary basis. I think the whose `stdin/stdout` issue was the **XY-Problem** that @iBug picked up on below.

Answer (score 2):

While you can break your tests up into multiple functions, since the number of cases you are handling is limited, simply including the tests directly in a single "state" loop that keeps track of the number of newlines and whether there have been any modifications to the input is an equally readable way to go. (good catch @iBug on the XY-Problem).

There are a number of ways to approach a character classification problem, which is essentially what you have. (meaning you read a character, classify whether if fits some predefined test, and then take some action depending on how it is classified). One efficient way to handle it is with a loop that keeps track of the state of things (e.g. "How many newlines have been sequentially read?", or whether I'm inside a word, reading whitespace, etc..) by setting, or resetting or incrementing a few variables that track whatever condition (or state) you are interested in that is based on something other than the current character.

You simply figure out what you need to follow (here, the number of sequential newlines, and whether you have modified the output in any way). Easy enough, just keep a count of the sequential newlines read in an integer like `nl` and keep an integer flag you set if you make any changes, call it `modified` or something logical. When you read anything other than a `'\n'` reset your newline count, e.g. `nl = 0;`.

Then it is just a matter of reading each character of input until you encounter `EOF` and conducting a number of tests to determine what character you read (either using `if, else if, else` or using a `switch` statement). Then for each different test, take the appropriate action.

For example, you could satisfy your criteria with something simple like:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {

    int c, modified = 0, nl = 0;

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {        /* loop over each char       */
        if (c == '\n') {                    /* am I a '\n'?              */
            if (nl < 2)                     /* have I ouput less than 2? */
                putchar ('\n');             /* output the newline        */
            else
                modified = 1;               /* set modified flag         */
            nl++;                           /* update the number seen    */
            continue;                       /* get next char             */
        }
        else if ('A' <= c && c <= 'Z') {    /* am I uppercase?           */
            putchar (c + 'a' - 'A');        /* convert to lowercase      */
            modified = 1;                   /* set modified flag         */
        }
        else if ('a' <= c && c <= 'z') {    /* am I lowercase?           */
            putchar (c + 'A' - 'a');        /* convert to uppercase      */
            modified = 1;                   /* set modified flag         */
        }
        else if (c < '0' || '9' < c) {      /* am I not a digit?         */
            if (c == ' ') {                 /* am I a space ?            */
                putchar (c);                /* output extra space        */
                modified = 1;               /* set modified flag         */
            }
            putchar (c);                    /* output unmodified char    */
        }
        nl = 0;                 /* reset newlines seen to zero */
    }

    return modified ? 0 : 1;    /* 0 - modified, 1 - stdout == stdin */
}
```

**note:** try and avoid using *magic numbers* in your code. If you need the ASCII value of `'A'`, then use `'A'`, not `65`. Reading thought code that has *magic numbers* scattered about (e.g. `65`, `32`, `10` is not nearly as informative as `'A'`, `' '` and `'\n'`).

Note also, you can use the macros is `ctype.h` (e.g. `isupper()`, `islower()`, `isdigit()`, etc..) to easily test what the current character is in a very readable manner. There is also learning value in doing it manually to gain an understanding of what those convenient functions in `ctype.h` are actually doing and practicing setting up your conditional tests properly.

**Example Input File**

Now just create a test case to exercise your character classifications and make sure you loop is working the way it should. There is nothing special required. Rather than trying to construct a myriad of `assert()` statements, just create an input file that has a character that fits each case:

```
$ cat dat/stateloop.txt
This Is a Line followed by THREE-newlines


and with SEVEN single-spaced asterisk * * * * * * *
aND a lINE fOLLOWED bY five nEWLINES ('\N')




And A Few Numbers zERO-tO-nINE (123456789)
1
a b c d e f g - A B C D E F G
Done2Day
```

**Example Use/Output**

Then carefully check the output:

```
$ ./bin/stateloop <dat/stateloop.txt
tHIS  iS  A  lINE  FOLLOWED  BY  three-NEWLINES

AND  WITH  seven  SINGLE-SPACED  ASTERISK  *  *  *  *  *  *  *
And  A  Line  Followed  By  FIVE  Newlines  ('\n')

aND  a  fEW  nUMBERS  Zero-To-Nine  ()

A  B  C  D  E  F  G  -  a  b  c  d  e  f  g
dONEdAY
```

**Check Return Value**

and validate the `return` is correct.

```
$ echo $?
0
```

**Try A (no-change) Case**

Do the same thing for the non-modified case:

```
$ printf "~@##$@#$%%#*[]{};:^^&&*)\n" | ./bin/stateloop
~@###$%#*[]{};:^^&&*)
```

**Check Appropriate Return**

```
$ echo $?
1
```

As noted earlier, there are many ways to approach this type of problem. Just find something that is logical, robust, readable and understandable. Good luck with your coding.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're facing an XY problem.

From your description I read that the actual thing you want to do is **to check whether the output is identical to the input**. So the solution is simple: You just need to track if at least one character has been modified during the process, and if yes then you know the input and the output will be different.

```
int modified = 0;

void testChars(int iochar){
    while(iochar != EOF){
        if (iochar == 10){
            iochar = newline(iochar);
        } else if(iochar == 32) {
            space(iochar);
            modified++;
        } else if (iochar > 64 && iochar < 91) {
            upperCase(iochar);
            modified++;
        } else if (iochar < 123 && iochar > 96) {
            lowerCase(iochar);
            modified++;
        } else if (iochar < 58 && iochar > 47) {
            digit();
            modified++;
        } else {
            putchar(iochar);
            // Nothing modified
        }

        iochar = getchar();
    }
}

int newline(int iochar){
    int count = 0;
    while (iochar == 10){
        if (count < 2) {
            putchar(iochar);
        } else {
            modified++;
        }
        count++; 
        iochar = getchar();
    }
    return iochar;
}
```

Then test if `modified == 0` and you'll know it.

Comment: Quibbles: `modified` should be set to one rather than incremented, to avoid overflow. `count` should be similarly limited. `10` should be `’\n’`. The hardcoded character manipulations should instead use `isdigit`, `isupper`, `tolower`, *etc.*

Comment: @EricPostpischil I just copied OP's code and applied minimal modification to it.